# require() does not work in solidity code?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, syntax-highlighting

> I defined a function in my contract as follows: (**summarized code**)

```
struct StateStruct {
        bytes32 description;
        mapping(bytes32 => bytes32) sub_state;
    }

    struct ObjectStruct {
        StateStruct state;
        address owner; 
        bool isObject;

        bytes32 review;
    }

    function isObject(bytes32 _id) public view returns(bool isIndeed) {
            return objectStructs[_id].isObject;
        }

    function newObjectReview(bytes32 _id, bytes32 _review,  address _owner) public returns(bool success) {
            require(!isObject(_id));

            objectStructs[_id].owner = _owner;
            objectStructs[_id].isObject = true;

            objectStructs[_id].review = _review;

            emit LogNewObjectReview(msg.sender, _id, _review, _owner);

            objectList.push(_id);

            return true;
        }
```

However, apparently, `require(!isObject(_id));` does not work. Because in case previously an object with `_id = 100` has been generated, it is generated with same `_id = 100` **indefinitely** !

But I defined this line of code (`require(!isObject(_id));`) to prevent this situation, such that an object `_id` would be **unique**.

However, transaction for generating a new object with **repeated** `_id` is done **successfully** and I receive a **transaction hash** !

You can see full code of my contract with JavaScript code bellow.

> solidity code : (Full source code)

```
pragma solidity 0.4.23; 

contract RFID {

    struct StateStruct {
        bytes32 description;
        mapping(bytes32 => bytes32) sub_state;
    }

    struct ObjectStruct {
        StateStruct state;
        address owner; 
        bool isObject;

        bytes32 review;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => ObjectStruct) objectStructs;
    bytes32[] public objectList;

    event LogNewObject(address sender, bytes32 indexed id, bytes32 sub_states_types, bytes32 sub_states_values, address owner);
    event LogChangeObjectState(address sender, bytes32 indexed id, bytes32 sub_states_types, bytes32 sub_states_values);
    event LogChangeObjectOwner(address sender, bytes32 indexed id, address newOwner);

    event LogNewObjectReview(address sender, bytes32 indexed _id, bytes32 _review,  address _owner);
    event LogChangeObjectStateReview(address sender, bytes32 indexed id, bytes32 _review);

    function isObject(bytes32 _id) public view returns(bool isIndeed) {
        return objectStructs[_id].isObject;
    }

    function getObjectCount() public view returns(uint count) {
        return objectList.length;
    }

    /*function setArraySize(uint256 _number_of_sub_states) public {

        number_of_sub_states = _number_of_sub_states;

    }

    function getArraySize() view public returns (uint256) {
       return number_of_sub_states;
    }*/

    function newObject(bytes32 _id, uint256 number_of_sub_states, bytes32[10] sub_states_types, bytes32[10] sub_states_values, address _owner) public returns(bool success) {
        require(!isObject(_id));

        uint256 counter=0;
        for(counter; counter < number_of_sub_states; counter++) {

            objectStructs[_id].state.sub_state[sub_states_types[counter]] = sub_states_values[counter];

            emit LogNewObject(msg.sender, _id, bytes32(sub_states_types[counter]), bytes32(sub_states_values[counter]), _owner);

        }

        objectStructs[_id].owner = _owner;
        objectStructs[_id].isObject = true;

        objectList.push(_id);

        return true;
    }

    function newObjectReview(bytes32 _id, bytes32 _review,  address _owner) public returns(bool success) {
        require(!isObject(_id));

        objectStructs[_id].owner = _owner;
        objectStructs[_id].isObject = true;

        objectStructs[_id].review = _review;

        emit LogNewObjectReview(msg.sender, _id, _review, _owner);

        objectList.push(_id);

        return true;
    }

    function changeObjectState(bytes32 _id, uint256 number_of_sub_states, bytes32[10] sub_states_types, bytes32[10] sub_states_values) public returns(bool success) {
        require(isObject(_id));
        uint256 counter=0;
        for(counter; counter < number_of_sub_states; counter++) {

            objectStructs[_id].state.sub_state[sub_states_types[counter]] = sub_states_values[counter];

            emit LogChangeObjectState(msg.sender, _id, bytes32(sub_states_types[counter]), bytes32(sub_states_values[counter]));

        }

        return true;
    }

    function changeObjectStateReview(bytes32 _id, bytes32 _review) public returns(bool success) {
        require(isObject(_id));

        objectStructs[_id].review = _review;

        emit LogChangeObjectStateReview(msg.sender, _id, _review);

        return true;
    }

    function changeObjectOwner(bytes32 _id, address _newOwner) public returns(bool success) {
        require(isObject(_id));
        objectStructs[_id].owner = _newOwner;
        emit LogChangeObjectOwner(msg.sender, _id, _newOwner);
        return true;
    }

}
```

> JavaScript and HTML code :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Weechain Smart Contract</title>



    <script src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace
}
</style>

<style>
.input {
    background-color: #373E43;
    color: black;
}
</style>

<style>
.header {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #373E43;
    color: white;
}
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 15px;
}
</style>

<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #373E43; color: white;}
tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #373E43; color: white;}
</style>

<style>
.output {
background-color: #373E43; 
color: white;
text-align: center;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="w3-container">

    <div class="header">
  <h1>NFC Smart Contract</h1>
</div>

        <!-- <p>Output: <span id="owner"></span> 
        </p> -->
        <div class="output">
        <p id="Output" >  </p>
        </div>

<div class="row">
<div class="input">
  <div class="column">

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Object ID</label>
        <input id="_idNew" class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="text" style="width:30%"> 

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Maintenance Review</label>
        <input id="_reviewNew" class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="text" style="width:30%"> 

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Object Owner Address</label>
        <input id="Address" class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="text" style="width:30%"> 

        <button id="buttonNewObject" class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large">Create New Object</button>

        <!-- <button id="buttonGet" class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large">Get Energy Balance</button> -->

   </div>
   <div class="column">

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Object ID</label>
        <input id="_idUpdate" class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="text" style="width:30%"> 

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Maintenance Review</label>
        <input id="_reviewUpdate" class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="text" style="width:30%"> 

        <button id="buttonUpdateObject" class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large">Update Review</button>

        <!-- <button id="buttonGetPower" class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large">Get Power Balance</button> -->

   </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="row">
        <div>
          <h2 class="sub-header">New Objects Transactions</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Transaction Hash</th>
                  <th>Object ID</th>
                  <th>Maintenance Review</th>
                  <th>Object Owner Address</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="transactionsNewObjects">
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div>
          <h2 class="sub-header">Maintenance Review Updates Transactions</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Transaction Hash</th>
                  <th>Object ID</th>
                  <th>Maintenance Review</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="transactionsUpdates">
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

    <script>
       if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
           web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
       } else {
           web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
       }

       //this.watchEvents = this.watchEvents.bind(this)

       web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
/*
       var CoursetroContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_fName","type":"string"},{"name":"_age","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setInstructor","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getInstructor","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"},{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]);
*/
    var CoursetroContract = web3.eth.contract([
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "sender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "id",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "_review",
                "type": "bytes32"
            }
        ],
        "name": "LogChangeObjectStateReview",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_id",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "name": "_newOwner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "changeObjectOwner",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_id",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "name": "number_of_sub_states",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "sub_states_types",
                "type": "bytes32[10]"
            },
            {
                "name": "sub_states_values",
                "type": "bytes32[10]"
            }
        ],
        "name": "changeObjectState",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_id",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "name": "_review",
                "type": "bytes32"
            }
        ],
        "name": "changeObjectStateReview",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_id",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "name": "number_of_sub_states",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "sub_states_types",
                "type": "bytes32[10]"
            },
            {
                "name": "sub_states_values",
                "type": "bytes32[10]"
            },
            {
                "name": "_owner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "newObject",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "sender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "_id",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "_review",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "_owner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "LogNewObjectReview",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "sender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "id",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "newOwner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "LogChangeObjectOwner",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_id",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "name": "_review",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "name": "_owner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "newObjectReview",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "sender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "id",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "sub_states_types",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "sub_states_values",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "LogNewObject",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "sender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "id",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "sub_states_types",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "sub_states_values",
                "type": "bytes32"
            }
        ],
        "name": "LogChangeObjectState",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getObjectCount",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "count",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_id",
                "type": "bytes32"
            }
        ],
        "name": "isObject",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "isIndeed",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "objectList",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "bytes32"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]);

       var Coursetro = CoursetroContract.at('0xcdde728e484a53a4879f4a679b9872619bfbdcc9');

       $("#buttonNewObject").click(function() {
    var estd_gas = Coursetro.newObjectReview.estimateGas($("#_idNew").val(), $("#_reviewNew").val(), $("#Address").val());
    console.log(estd_gas);
    var params = {
        gas: Math.round(estd_gas * 1.25),
        from: web3.eth.accounts[0]
    };

    Coursetro.newObjectReview.sendTransaction($("#_idNew").val(), $("#_reviewNew").val(), $("#Address").val(), params, function(error, TxHash) {
           if (!error) {

               $("#Output").html('Transaction Hash in Hexadecimal:'+ TxHash.toString());//+' ('+TxHash[1]+')');
               $('#transactionsNewObjects').append('<tr><td>' + TxHash.toString() + '</td><td>' + $("#_idNew").val() + '</td><td>' + $("#_reviewNew").val() + '</td><td>' + $("#Address").val() + '</td></tr>')
               console.log(TxHash.toString());

           } else
                console.log(error);
       });
});



   $("#buttonUpdateObject").click(function() {
    var estd_gas = Coursetro.changeObjectStateReview.estimateGas($("#_idUpdate").val(), $("#_reviewUpdate").val());
    console.log(estd_gas);
    var params = {
        gas: Math.round(estd_gas * 1.25),
        from: web3.eth.accounts[0]
    };

    Coursetro.changeObjectStateReview.sendTransaction($("#_idUpdate").val(), $("#_reviewUpdate").val(), params, function(error, TxHash) {
           if (!error) {

               $("#Output").html('Transaction Hash in Hexadecimal:'+ TxHash.toString());//+' ('+TxHash[1]+')');
               $('#transactionsUpdates').append('<tr><td>' + TxHash.toString() + '</td><td>' + $("#_idUpdate").val() + '</td><td>' + $("#_reviewUpdate").val() + '</td></tr>')
               console.log(TxHash.toString());

           } else
                console.log(error);
       });
});





    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

> **IMPORTANT UPDATE : I added summarized source code of my contract in my question.**
>
> **IMPORTANT NOTE :  Is there any method to show a warning message in the UI in case an object with a "`repeated _id`" is created.**

Comment: `require()` definitely works. It's a little too much code to wade through to replicate the issue. Consider reducing it to a little contract we can play with.

Comment: receiving a transaction hash doesn't mean the transaction has been executed correctly. Please check the transaction receipt and you might see the status as 0 (error)

Comment: @Rob Hitchens Thank you. Sorry for delay in response. I added summarized code of my contract in my question. The section that is related to my question. If you have any other question, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @mirg Thank you. but is there any method to show a message in the UI in case an object with a "repeated id" is created. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried your contract in remix and it is working as expected the second transaction to `newObjectReview()` with the same id is rejected. It might As stated by mirg it be your transactions are failing for some other reason like running out of gas.

Comment: @Ismael Thank you. Could you please write here exactly your remix input (bytes32 _id, bytes32 _review,  address _owner) ? Also, do you have some suggestion for my note at the end of my question ? i.e. " Is there any method to show a warning message in the UI in case an object with a "repeated _id" is created ?" Thanks

Comment: The parameters were `_id="0x32",_review="0x23",_owner="0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c"`. You already have a function `isObject()` but that will not work until your transaction has been mined. One approach to avoid repeating ids is to have a counter in the contract and always use that as id, and incremente for each new object. The id is returned to the user in the event so with the transaction hash it can be recovered from the transaction receipt.

Comment: @Ismael Thank you. Does it mean you choose : `_id = 2 , _review = #` ? And if so, do you know why in case of  `GUI` we don't need to convert our inputs from `ascii` to `Hex` but in `remix` we need to convert it ? Thanks

Comment: The type of the first two parameters is bytes32 and I used the hexadecimal notation because it is more convenient. I don't know why that is mandatory in remix. If you create your own interface you can decide how you want to input your data. But I always prefer to enforce the correct types, the users can make mistakes and web3 is not very good dealing with invalid data. For example if you accept an string for a bytes32 input you have to ensure it is less than 32 bytes, not 32 characters because some characters use more than 1 byte.

Comment: @Ismael Thank you. And in case of inserting converted inputs (for example :  `_review = 0x666972737420726576696577`) is it possible to see a readable version of `_review` (i.e. `first review` in format of `ascii`) in https://etherscan.io/ ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think etherscan will display bytes32 as ascii or utf8 strings. But i think this conversation is of off-topic here, if you have more doubts it is better to ask a new question.